# Array to function to int arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to get the value of an integer from within a struct pointer. Simply: `int cool = *(*(&(coolPtr->map)) + x);` can this be simplified? The rest of the code is context. X being the index of the array.

```
struct Cool {
    int map[5];
};


int value (Cool* coolPtr, int x) {

    return *(*(&(coolPtr->map)) + x); // Here
} 


int main() {

// Test
Cool* foo = new Cool;

// Fill
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) foo->map[i] = i*4;

// Check
cout << value(foo, 3); cout << endl; // 12, correct
cout << value(foo, 4); cout << endl; // 16, correct
```

Comment: @200_success that was not hypothetical code, that is my exact code. I just trimmed off the last bracket, namespace and including <iostream>. Try it, it compiles, I did not think those were needed, as anyone looking at that would see that it is functioning code. That is why I had a question, I had done it that way (posted code,) and I was wondering if there was a better way to do that. That, being the chain of pointers and references, commented with // here.

Comment: What is the `Cool` struct for?

Comment: @200_success just the name of an example struct with an array within. I needed to do this exact thing in my project, only with other names. This was to see how I could do this, before implementing it in my project. So this example stands alone...

Comment: We don't review example code here. If we can't tell what the task is that the code accomplishes, then the simple answer is going to be "well, don't do that". Hence our insistence that you tell us what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Makes sense, I misunderstood "hypothetical" with "pseudo." Just to add, it's implementation would be: Cool changed to Map, map[5] with map[1024]. Value function the same (the part I was wondering.) In main I declare Map almost at the beginning. Fill would be filled with 0's and 1's. Then within the controls I call Value() to check for a 0 or a 1. The main project is a game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should use one of the myriad accepted standard formatting-conventions.

   The things which stand out like a sore thumb are the newlines you have at the beginning of your two functions, the body of your for-loop being on the same line, and of course the content of `main` (which somehow lost it's closing bracket) having lost one level of indentation.
   Maybe the last is an artifact of not checking how it looks after posting here? Having taken a look at the source, that explanation seems unsatisfying...
2. You should avoid `using namespace std;` (The other line you omitted is obviously `#include <iostream>`). It's a plague and just biding its time to bite you later.
   [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
3. Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl` unless you might need to flush there.
4. You can chain uses of the stream-inserter.
5. Don't ever allocate something dynamically without a really good reason, and then use smart-pointers.
6. Your `value`-function isn't complex enough to be usefully extracted into a function in general.
   Still, let's dissect the expression:

   ```
   *(*(&(coolPtr->map)) + x);
   ```

   Which is:

   ```
   1. dereference `coolptr` and get member `map`
   2. take the address
   3. dereference (undoing last step)
   4. add `x`
   5. dereference (equal to indexing with `x` together with step 4)
   ```

   Equivalent:

   ```
   coolptr->map[x];
   ```

Comment: I took the liberty to undelete this nice answer, I hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that can be simplified at lot.

```
*(&(coolPtr->map))
```

The `*` and `&` "cancel out" (assuming the expression is well-formed and both are otherwise legal), so you can drop them both, which leaves you with:

```
*(coolPtr->map + x)
```

Which people will recognize as the expanded form of array access, so you can put it back into its usual form:

```
coolPtr->map[x]
```